# Customization of Bootstrap carousel's width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How to customize the width of a carousel via bootstrap or css, please?

I'm currently mainly using this code into my web page:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I've tried to set a width to the body, but it wouldn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide a link to your project

Comment: @Aibrean, it's just bootstrap

Comment: I don't assume people haven't made their own customizations.

Comment: @Aibrean, I didn't. I'm just using the default bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to set width of carousel as

1. set container width and include carousel in that container, this width can be customized as

   ```
   .container {
       width : // here enter your custom width
   }
   ```

Overwrite this over default bootstrap css/less. And don't forget to add media queries to adjust width since this will apply globally.

2. secondly you can change carousel items inner width with class as below

   ```
   .carousel-inner {
       width: // here enter your custom width;
   }
   ```

This will just affect width of carousel

Comment: enter your custom css after bootstrap css file

Answer (score 0):

Width is relative to the parent container the carousel is in. So you need to set the width on the ID/class of the div you are wrapping the carousel inside. You could also set it inside a bootstrap container (and change the container width globally) or inside a column for more lax specificity.